# Set range of indexes in array aggregation MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, range, aggregation

My database looks like:

```
{email:"user", contacts: 
 [
  {emailContact:"test", firstName:"test", lastName:"test", messages:
   [
    {email:"user", content:"hi", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"test", content:"how are you?", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"user", content:"im fine", date:"ISODate(...)"}
   ]
  },
  {emailContact:test2, firstName:"test2", lastName:"test2", messages:
   [
    {email:"user", content:"hahaha", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"test2", content:"yea thats right", date:"ISODate(...)"}
    {email:"user", content:"xd", date:"ISODate(...)"}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

And I have to get messages of specific indexes.
For example messages with 4,5,6 index.

I've tried already several similar:

```
db.contacts.aggregation([{$match:{email:"elo@elo.pl"}},{$unwind:'$contacts'},{$match:{'contacts.emailContact':'user@user.pl'}},{$unwind:'$contacts.messages'},{$project:{email:1,content:1,date:{$slice:['$contacts.messages',4,6]}}},{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:'$contacts.messages'}}])
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$skip` and `$limit` are your friends.

Say you have to get messages from 4 to 6, you would `$skip` the first three documents and `$limit` your result to get the number of documents you want (in this case also three because you want 4, 5, 6):

```
db.contacts.aggregate([
  {$match: {email: 'user'}},
  {$unwind: '$contacts'},
  {$match: {'contacts.emailContact': 'test'}},
  {$unwind: '$contacts.messages'},
  {$sort: {'contacts.messages.date': -1}},
  {$skip: 3},
  {$limit: 3},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$contacts.messages'}}
])
```

I suggest you check the documentation on aggregations anyway, it's well written and full of examples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/